# Fitted values from a different model in R

Tags: r

I was wondering whether it is possible to compute fitted values for a sample of observations which is different from the subsample that has been used to perform a linear regression. In particular, I have a full dataframe of 400 individuals. I want to perform two separate OLS regressions, subsampling the dataframe according to the value of a dummy.

```
ols1<-lm(log_consumption ~ log_wage + Age + Age2 + Education, data=df,  subset = type==1)
ols2<-lm(log_consumption ~ log_wage + Age + Age2 + Education, data=df, subset = type==0)
```

this code obviously returns me the two separate models and the corresponding fitted values. However I would like to get the fitted values of all my dataframe (i.e. the fitted values of all the 400 individuals) firstly according to model 1, then according to model 2. Basically I want to compare the fitted values for the entire dataframe exploiting the differences among the OLS coefficients that I get under the two different "regimes".

Is there a way to do this in R??

Thanks for your help,
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to `predict()`. Try: `predict(ols1, df)` and `predict(ols2, df)`. Here is an example using the iris data set.

```
## data  
df <- iris
df$type <- rep(c(0, 1), 75) # 75 type 0 and 75 type 1

## models
ols1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width,
           data = df, subset = type == 1)
ols2 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width,
           data = df, subset = type == 0)

## predicted values for all the 150 observations
# just for checking: fitted(ols1) and fitted(ols2) give the 75 fitted values
length(fitted(ols1))
length(fitted(ols2))
# here, we want predicted values instead of fitted values
# the the predict() function, we can obtained predicted values for all the 150 observations
predict(ols1, df)
predict(ols2, df)
# check: we have 150 observations
length(predict(ols1, df))
length(predict(ols2, df))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It was much easier I was expecting. Still a beginner with R.. problem solved.